# Maya .ma matrix scale translation

Tags: import, matrix, transformation, maya

A perhaps slightly off-topic subject, but Maya is giving me serious grief on a specific scale translation matrix transformation, and I have nowhere else to turn.

Everything works fine with my Maya .ma (Maya ASCII) importer until Maya descides to add an .spt attribute (typically `setAttr ".spt" -type "double3" 1 2 3 ;`). From [this](http://caad.arch.ethz.ch/info/maya/manual/Commands/xform.html) somewhat vague documentation I came to the conclusion that the three .spt values go into the scale translate matrix.

I would very, *very* much appreciate any pointers you could give me on how to handle .spt in my matrix transformations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too tired to think straight, and after some hours of sleep I realized that the problem lie not in the transforms, but in the pivot. I managed to guess how the pivot was constructed, namely from the two attributes `.rp + .spt`.

Dalai Lama is right about sleep. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a nasty hack, but could your importer add in the reverse transformation to undo what Maya is doing to your stuff on import?